# Get a list of files based on creation date

Tags: c#, .net, linq, file, data-structures

I'm attempting to compile a list of file names (with "stat" and "kill" file extensions), where the files should be ordered in the list based on creation date. I've tried using the LINQ `OrderBy` clause, but could not specify the date. This is my current logic:

```
var fileList = Directory.EnumerateFiles(userPath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".stat", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || s.EndsWith(".kill", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

How could I sort them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead - it returns sequence of [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) objects which have CreationTime property:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(userPath);
var fileList = dir.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                  .Where(f => f.Extension.Equals(".stat", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || 
                              f.Extension.Equals(".kill", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                  .OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime);
```

Also you can use `Extension` property to get file extension.

Comment: `CreationDate` does not seem to exist - do I need to import something?

Comment: @DotNET sorry,it should be [CreationTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @DotNET welcome, I would go with FileInfo if there is no performance requirements or performance issues, because I find it more readable. If you will have performance issues, then consider to use Tim's option (also read my last suggestion in comments of his answer)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`File.GetCreationTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in `Enumerable.OrderBy`. You can also use the `Path` class:

```
var fileList = Directory.EnumerateFiles(userPath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Select(p => new { Path = p, Extension = Path.GetExtension(p) })
    .Where(x => x.Extension.Equals(".stat", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || x.Extension.Equals(".kill", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    .OrderBy(x => File.GetCreationTime(x.Path))
    .Select(x => x.Path);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tested it and it proves to work. However I feel that the other answer is a bit more elegant, and thus I have chosen to adopt that :) Thanks for the help, +1!

Comment: @DotNET: Note that `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` is less efficient since every `FileInfo` object must be intialized with all properties like `Length` whereas `Directory.GetFiles` just returns the paths. I would use the static `Directory/File` methods as long as i can. So you could create `FileInfo` objects **after** you have applied the filter, so behind the `Where`. But that's micro-optimization if you only have few files in one folder.

Comment: @TimSchmelter basically I agree with you, especially when you need to get only one info about file. When you have to request several properties of file, than FileInfo can avoid additional security checks. But if performance is a real goal, then I would concat two queries here - one which gets `*.stat*` files and one which gets `*.kill*` files. And only then applied filtering with `GetCreationTime` as you suggested